# help to understanding the past participle form

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

i want know what type of sentence is it and why do we use past participle here and 2nd example i took from (Alan Walker song Faded)

1)You will be shocked?
2)I am faded

Comment: More context is needed in 1). It could mean *you will be surprised* or someone or something will give you an electric shock. In 2), *faded* could be slang, so you need to listen to the whole song to understand the intended meaning better. (But note that lyric interpretation is usually considered off-topic on ELL.)

Comment: "I am faded" is a poetic use (appropriate to a song lyric). It is not something that anybody is likely to say in ordinary speech.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of these sentences is Subject + [Linking Verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_verb) + Adjective. The purpose of this kind of sentence is basically to describe the subject.

Examples:

- The dog was hungry.
- The box is red.
- We are tired.
- You will be shocked.
- I am faded.

The past [participle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle) form (verb + "-ed") can be used as an adjective both in English and in several other European languages.

Examples:

- fade > faded > faded picture
- shock > shocked > shocked face
- wound > wounded > wounded leg
- tire > tired > tired boy
- worry > worried > worried mother
- dry > dried > dried fruit

Hope this helps!

Comment: this post can't help me because when i search on google it's does not faded verb is ajective

Comment: Maybe these pages will help:

Comment: Definition of [shocked](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shocked)

Comment: Definition of [faded](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/faded)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guy I read a little bit more I found this

Distinction between passive voice and participial adjective
A distinction is made between the above type of clause and a superficially similar construction where the past participle is used as an adjective, and the verb be or similar is simply a copula linking the subject of the sentence to that adjective. For example:

I am excited (right now).
is not passive voice, because the participle excited is used as an adjective denoting a state, not to as a verb (as it would in the passive the electron was excited with a laser pulse).

The above text is from the second link given below.

THE NEXT ONE WAS MY FIRST ANSWER

It is pasive voice structure.

It follows this structure Subject + to be + past participle.

It can be used in any other tenses like future Subject + will/going to + to be + past participle.

Or perfect tenses for example Subject + have + been+ to be + past participle.

Take a look [here](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/passive) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice)

Comment: "I am excited" is the passive form of "[something] excites me".  You can only say that participles are sometimes verbs and sometimes adjectives if you take the shallowest view of grammar.